# Vue.js auto dismiss alert from Vuex store

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuex

I can't seem to figure out how to auto dismiss my alerts. I am storing the alerts in Vuex, and I am creating the alerts via actions. There could be any number of alerts, and they should be dismissed in the order in which they where created.  For illustration purposes, I am creating a number of alerts, one every 700 milliseconds.  I would like the alerts to auto dismiss in the order in which they were created, after a set amount of time.  I am not sure how to do this or if there is a better way to handle global alert messages that aren't part of Vuex. Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/thL4rLta/1/

```
/*------ Animations ------*/
Vue.transition('fade', {
  enterClass: 'fadeInDown',
  leaveClass: 'fadeOutUp'
})

/* ----- Store ----- */
const state = {
  items: []
};

const mutations = {
  SHOW_ALERT (state, data) {
    data.id = Date.now()
    state.items.push(data)
  },
  HIDE_ALERT (state, item) {
     state.items.$remove(item)
  },
};

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations
});

/* ----- Component ----- */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  vuex: {
    getters: {
      alerts: (state) => state.items
    },
    actions: {
      hideAlert: ({ dispatch }, alert) => dispatch('HIDE_ALERT', alert)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    dismiss (e) {
      this.hideAlert(e)
    }
  }
});

// Creat alerts
function doSetTimeout (i) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    store.dispatch('SHOW_ALERT', {message: 'sdfsdf'})
  }, 700 * i)
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
  doSetTimeout(i)
}
```

Template:

```
<div class='test' id="app">
  <div v-for="alert in alerts" 
      class="animated alert alert-dismissible alert-danger" 
      transition="fade" 
      v-bind:class="alert.type" 
      role="alert">
      <button @click="dismiss(alert)"type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    {{alert.message}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/thL4rLta/2/

Basically, you create a custom directive:

```
Vue.directive('delay', {
  params: ['cb'],
  bind: function () {
    setTimeout(this.params.cb, 3000)
  }
})
```

Which you can add to the v-for, with a callback as a parameter

```
<div class='test' id="app">
  <div v-for="alert in alerts" v-delay :cb="()=>{dismiss(alert)}"  
      class="animated alert alert-dismissible alert-danger" 
      transition="fade" 
      v-bind:class="alert.type" 
      role="alert">
      <button @click="dismiss(alert)"type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    {{alert.message}}
  </div>
</div>
```